# Haar Cascaded Classifier Data in OpenCV:

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, haar-wavelet

I can't find any information about Data used for training Haar classifiers in OpenCV. I want to know what kind of, how many and how(manually or via program) these classifiers were generated.

You can find these classifier's xml files in **..OpenCV2.3.1\opencv\data\haarcascades..** directory. Thanks

Comment: I see, you want to build your own database. Can't help you on that, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this research paper contains the answer

[Empirical Analysis of Detection Cascades of Boosted Classifiers for Rapid Object
Detection by Dr Rainer Lienhart](http://www.lienhart.de/Prof._Dr._Rainer_Lienhart/Publications_files/MRL-TR-May02-revised-Dec02_1.pdf)

thanks guys for the help...